# Symfony doctrine:generate:entities How to find is and has methods

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, console, code-generation, getter

I have an entity called Member with a boolen property called "active". When I generate the getters and setters with `doctrine:generate:entities` I get the methods `getActive()` and `setActive()`. Now I rename the getter to `isActive`. When I now call `doctrine:generate:entities` on this entity again, the process generates a new method `getActive` as he does not find the method `isActive`.

Is there a way to tell it to search for `is` and `has` getter methods too?

Comment: Related: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible at the moment. You can vote for this feature here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2287. However it is not recommended to use the "doctrine:generate:entities"-command to update entities. The command was built to generate the entities for the first time and not to update them. You should maintain your entities with your ide.

Comment: Doesn't seems to have that much of an priority :) I will start there, thanks.